# Filter and print Json output

Tags: python, json

i am looking for help on printing json data with filters defined.

Below is my actual output but i want to print only fields i need as defined in expecting output below.

```
{
 "response": {
  "@status": "success",
  "result": {
   "enabled": "yes",
   "group": {
    "mode": "Active-Active",
    "local-info": {
     "url-compat": "Match",
     "app-version": "xxxxxx",
     "gpclient-version": "Not Installed",
     "build-rel": "xxxxx",
     "ha2-port": "dedicated-ha2",
     "av-version": "0",
     "ha2-keep-alive": "split-datapath",
     "url-version": "0000.00.00.000",
     "ha1-backup-ipaddr": "xxxxx",
     "mgmt-hb": "configured",
     "platform-model": "xxxx",
     "av-compat": "Match",
     "vpnclient-compat": "Match",
     "ha1-ipaddr": "xxxxx",
     "ha1-backup-macaddr": "xxxxxx",
     "vpnclient-version": "Not Installed",
     "ha2-macaddr": "xxxxxx",
     "monitor-fail-holdup": "0",
     "priority": "100",
     "preempt-hold": "1",
     "state": "active-primary",
     "version": "1",
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

what am i using in my code:

```
      json_data = json.dumps(output)
  

      print (json_data[0][mode])
```

Expecting output :

{

"mode": "Active-Active",

"state": "active-primary",

}

...

Output I get:
{

Comment: Your question is not complete. What's your output ?

Comment: do you want to print only what you include in the expecting output or and something else because you use the`...`

Comment: What is *output*? Is it a Python dictionary? If it is then *json_data* will be a string in which case your attempt at printing will fail because a Python char (json_data[0]) is not subscriptable.

Comment: I need to filter actual output and get expected output

Comment: There is no way that the code you've shown will emit a single left-brace. Please show your actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your output by trying this:

```
import json

output = {
 "response": {
  "@status": "success",
  "result": {
   "enabled": "yes",
   "group": {
    "mode": "Active-Active",
    "local-info": {
     "url-compat": "Match",
     "app-version": "xxxxxx",
     "gpclient-version": "Not Installed",
     "build-rel": "xxxxx",
     "ha2-port": "dedicated-ha2",
     "av-version": "0",
     "ha2-keep-alive": "split-datapath",
     "url-version": "0000.00.00.000",
     "ha1-backup-ipaddr": "xxxxx",
     "mgmt-hb": "configured",
     "platform-model": "xxxx",
     "av-compat": "Match",
     "vpnclient-compat": "Match",
     "ha1-ipaddr": "xxxxx",
     "ha1-backup-macaddr": "xxxxxx",
     "vpnclient-version": "Not Installed",
     "ha2-macaddr": "xxxxxx",
     "monitor-fail-holdup": "0",
     "priority": "100",
     "preempt-hold": "1",
     "state": "active-primary",
     "version": "1",
    }
   }
  }
 }
}


json_data = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
  
print("Mode: "+ output["response"]["result"]["group"]["mode"])
print("State: "+ output["response"]["result"]["group"]["local-info"]["state"])
```

Comment: thank you for your input, really helped me. How can i print everything after "local-info" with all fields and their respective data??

Comment: @Kumar `print(json.dumps(output["response"]["result"]["group"]["local-info"], indent=4))
` with this line you can print the `local-info` data formatted as shown in the dictionary

Comment: @Kumar `print(output["response"]["result"]["group"]["local-info"])` and with this line you can print the `local-info` data in one line.

Comment: @Kumar if this answer solved your problem you can always accept it by clicking on the check mark